# convert function into find_if lambda

Tags: c++

I have some trouble to convert my function into a std::find_if lamnda.
below you can see my function

```
bool Room::ItemInRoomPresent(std::string & item)
{
    bool isPresent = false;
    for (std::vector<Item>::iterator i = m_RoomItems.begin(); i !=m_RoomItems.end(); i++)
    {
        if (i->GetName() == item)
        {
            item == i->GetName();
            isPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPresent;
}
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: `std::any_of` would seem more appropriate than `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, if you aren't interested in the position at which an item is found, just that there is at least one matching item anywhere in the sequence, you can use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and make this essentially a one-liner:

```
return std::any_of(m_RoomItems.begin(), 
                   m_RoomItems.end(),
                   [&](Item const& x) { return x.GetName() == item; });
```

The passed lambda is identical to Kerrek's version but the return value can be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m_RoomItems.begin(), m_RoomItems.end(),
                       [&](const Item& x) { return x.GetName() == item; });

return it != m_RoomItems.end();
```

(The statement `item == i->GetName();` in your `if` statement has no effect, so I omitted it.)

Comment: `return it != m_RoomItems.end();` perhaps? :)